# ABS, traction control and caution triangle lit up on dashboard

Tags: honda, accord, abs, warning-light, traction-control

My Honda Accord 2003 has the  caution sign, ABS & TCS lights permanently displayed on my dashboard for some weeks but did not affect the functionality of my car.

How can I clear this signs from the dashboard?

[image: Snapshot of dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

The three lights are related to the same issue. Something happened that forced the vehicle to disable the traction control and ABS systems.

A common cause is a bad wheel speed sensor, or an open in the wheel speed sensor wiring. There should be one on each wheel and the ABS system needs inputs from all sensors to function properly.

Just remember that this isn't the only possible point of failure, but it would be silly to overlook something which is so easy to verify.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the signs you need a code reader tool with that functionality - do be aware that if the fault is still there then the signs will come back on probably straight away.

To clear the lights permanently then the issues causing them have to be resolved - as pointed out sensors, wiring or "signal ring" or reluctor.

If you can do this work then fine, if not you have to get the work done by a mechanic / garage / shop.

Once the cause or causes have been solved the codes can be cleared and the ABS etc will resume working.